# Match List Value With DataFrame Column Value In Order To Extract Another Column Value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list, "L" and a DataFrame, "df" and I wish to extract a certain column value only where the L and a certain df column match.

```
L = [299]
Match = []

df:
['ID']    ['Num']
299       1
300       3
....      ....
```

I wish to see 1 when I print Match:

```
print(Match):

1
```

Comment: This will do `df[df['ID'] == L[0]]`

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Match = df.loc[df['ID'].isin(L),'Num']
```

Comment: If there are multiple row matches how could you select only the first one?